# Python socket is on different port to the one I ask for

Tags: python, sockets

I coded up the simple server and client on this page:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication

In the code the port 5005 is specified, but when I run them, the server reports that other ports were used (e.g. 5807, 5810). Why is this?

(I'm running Anaconda python 2.7.8 through pycharm on Windows 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different ports, because this Source port for client and it's taken randomly.

Target Server Socket `5005`, must working fine.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what you're saying :(

Comment: Your `Client` opens random port and then connecting to the `Server` port at 5005. That Random port `client` must open to send a message

Comment: So you are saying: a client has to send through a port on its own computer. This is chosen randomly. The server is reporting what port was used on the client, not on the server itself?

Comment: At which point does the client choose a random port? Is it during `socket` creation, `connect` or `send` ? And how do I ask on the client side which port it has randomly chosen?